# hibernate collections with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

My case is a form, with categories, questions, answers... A form has different categories, each of one have different questions and this questions one or more possible answers.

In my imnplementation of java, I hava an object called TreeObject that implements all relationship between elements (and other common properties as creation date...). This object has a list of childs and a parent to follow the hierarchy of the form. Then, Category, Form and other elements extends this class and add some extra functionality.

The database will be a table with all common data (tree object) and childs and parent relationship, and some other tables (forms, categories, ...) with specific data for each one. For this I use `InheritanceType.JOINED`

The code of the Tree Object class (UPDATED to include @kostja comments):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TREE_OBJECTS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class TreeObject implements ITreeObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "CHILDRENS_RELATIONSHIP")
    private List<TreeObject> children;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private TreeObject parent;

    //More parameters, getters and setters. 
}
```

For example the Form class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FORMS")
public class Form extends TreeObject {

    private String name;

    //setters, getters and other stuff.
}
```

And the DAO has this method (I am using generics for simplifying the code but the code can be read):

```
 public T makePersistent(T entity) {
    setCreationInfo(entity);
    setUpdateInfo(entity);
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return entity;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
 }
```

Category, Questions and other elements are very similar to the Form class. The I skip them.

The **problem is that the children list** is not persisted correctly. For example the next test fails because getChildren().size() is 0 and not 1 (but other forms values are retrieved correctly, only the child list is empty):

```
 @Test
 public void storeFormWithCategory() throws NotValidChildException {
    Form form = new Form();
    form.setName("Test Form");
    Category category = new Category();
    form.addChild(category);
    formDao.makePersistent(form);
    Form retrievedForm = formDao.read(form.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(retrievedForm.getId(), form.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(retrievedForm.getChildren().size(), 1);
}
```

If I move the code of the child list into the Form class, it works correctly and the test is passed. But the list inside the parent class is not working. I cannot understand why, the only difference is the use of the inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved removing the Interface. I have read that hibernate cannot work with intefaces, and this is the reason why children parameter is not implemented with interfaces. Removing the interface implementation and changing some setters and getters methods (as getChildren) to use TreeObject solve the issue. I have thinked that not using the interface with the DAO was enought to solve this issue. But seems that the getters and setters of the object also must not use the inteface.

Probably, when I have copied to Form object I haven't use the interface as a quick copy paste, and this is the reason why has worked correctly in this case.